# Boisik font in combination with fontspec

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, metafont

I'm trying to use `fontspec` (XeLaTeX) in combination with the `Boisik` font, which turns out to be hard.

The following order

```
\usepackage{boisik}
\usepackage{fontspec}
```

leads to `fontspec` overriding `Boisik` with Latin Modern, and I can't seem to recover it (except for the Math, which remains `Boisik`).

The other order,

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{boisik}
```

I get `! LaTeX Error: This NFSS system isn't set up properly`.

The combination

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{boisik}
```

avoids the former error, but the result is as in the first case: Latin Modern everywhere but in the math.

Any other combination I could think of yields one of the same results as above.

So basically my question is, which would be the way to go to combine `Boisik` with a TTF font? Is there a way at all?

As a side note, I've tested the same with the `Fourier` font, and

```
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{fontspec}
```

produces the same result as with `Boisik` (math `Fourier`, text Latin Modern), while

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fourier}
```

does *not* produce an error but instead the very result I wanted: Fourier everywhere but the ability to use `fontspec` to include new font families for headings.

Any help is most appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Upon re-reading the question, I realized I did not try the following:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{boisik}
```

which is actually the solution. I'll leave it here for future reference. My apologies and thanks for your time.

**Edit**: Minimal working example as requested:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{boisik}

\newfontfamily{\arialFamily}{Arial}

\begin{document}
This document uses Boisik, but can change to {\arialFamily Arial} if desired.
\end{document}
```

[image: This document uses Boisik, but can change to Arial if desired.]

It is necessary to include `amssymb` before `\usepackage{boisik}` to resolve the issue of `LaTeX Error: Command '\hbar' already defined.`

Comment: Please always provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). Adding ``documentclass`` and ``begin{document}``, your example does not compile with ``XeLaTeX`` for me. I get ``LaTeX Error: Command `\hbar' already defined``.