# Symbol for Laplace Transform : 2 connected dots, one filled

Tags: math-mode, math-operators, transformation

What I want is the following:

`x(t) ●-o \hat{x}(f)` (The bar should be longer)

What is the name of the symbol in between and does it exist in LaTeX?

Comment: `\Laplace` with the `trfsigns` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `trsym` and the `trfsigns` packages both have this symbol (whose name, however, is not known to me). The symbol from the `trfsigns` package is somewhat longer but would perhaps benefit from some additional spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{trsym,trfsigns}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
x(t) \InversTransformHoriz \hat{x}(f)  % trsym package
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
x(t) \Laplace \hat{x}(f)               % trfsigns package
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Additionally, the `txfonts/pxfonts` and the `boisik` packages have `\multimapdotbothB`, which you could also use. However, the `txfonts/pxfonts` package will change the default font and the `boisik` package needs some [additional set up](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225150/boisik-font-in-combination-with-fontspec) when used with XeLaTeX.

Answer (score 4):

A closer look  through the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/ctan/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf)  also reveals the following aditional examples:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{txfonts}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
x(t) \multimapdotbothB \hat{x}(f)     
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
x(t) \imageof \hat{x}(f)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fdsymbol}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
x(t) \blackwhitespoon \hat{x}(f)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]